# template assign loop all in one array , but getting error

Tags: php, javascript, html

i'm trying to loop all the assign in only 1 array , but i get error like the image below,
can anyone teach me how?why is this error appear?many thanks

[image]

this is my template.php

```
class Template{
    private $vars = array();

    public function assign($key, $value){
        $this->vars[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function render($template_name){
        $path = $template_name. '.html';

        if(file_exists($path)){
            $contents = file_get_contents($path);

            foreach($this->vars as $key => $value){
                $contents = preg_replace('/\[' . $key . '\]/', $value, $contents);
            }
            $pattern = array(
                                '/\<\!\-\- if (.*) \-\-\>/',
                                '/\<\!\-\- else \-\-\>/',
                                '/\<\!\-\- endif \-\-\>/',
                                '/\<\!\-\- echo (.*) \-\-\>/'
                            );
            $replace = array(
                                '<?php if($1) : ?>',
                                '<?php else : ?>',
                                '<?php endif; ?>',
                                '<?php echo ($1) ?>'
                            );
            $contents = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $contents);

            eval(' ?>' . $contents . '<?php ');
        }else {
            exit('<h1>Template error!</h1>');
        }
    }

}

?>
```

assign for assigning value , then in my html can just write [value] to display it value

header.php

```
<?php

session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/class/template.php';

$game = '2';
$tech = '3';
$beauty = '4';
$bagua = '1';

$template = new Template;
$template->assign('sitename', 'site name');
$template->assign('title', '');

$code = array(
                'test1',
                'test2',
                'test3'
            );

$word = array(
                'haha1',
                'haha2',
                'haha3'
            );

$template->assign($code, $word);
$template->assign('test4', 'haha4');
$template->render('view/default/header');
?>
```

header.html

```
[test1][test2][test3][test4]
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Your `$key` is an array (`$code`), you can't assign an array as key of an other array (`$this->vars[$key]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a built-in PHP function that does what you want:
[array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

In your example code, you can do:

```
public function assign($key, $value){
    if(is_array($key)) {
        $this->vars = array_merge($this->vars, array_combine($key, $value));
    } else {
        $this->vars[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

or simply implement something similar using a `for` loop.

Comment: gettting error with this code , sry i can't understand how this code work

Comment: the `array_combine` creates a key-value array. It is then merged with the current `$this->vars` array, overwriting any overlapping existing keys. Note that `key` and `value` need to be of the same length and the elements of `key` have to be valid array keys.

Answer (score 0):

As Damien points out: You're trying to assign an array to the key of another array, which is throwing the error.

A nice solution here is to tweak the assign method to accept an array:

```
public function assign($key, $value = false)
{
    if (is_array($key))
    {
        foreach ($key as $k => $v) $this->vars[$k] = $v;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->vars[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Now you can send arrays or $key, $value to the assign method and it will handle either situation.

Or of course you can change the key your adding to be a string and not an array :)

Comment: just try it , same result...

what is the $k => $v stay for? and the $value=false?